# No mapping found for HTTP request

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am back with working in Springs. I used to work in Springs but blindly, didn't understand much. I used to get a lot of errors, very basic ones, and I am getting them again.

My problem is that, I don't know how the configuration of the `Spring-MVC` work.
*What happens when I run the project from my STS?*
I am working on the spring template project in STS.

I am getting this when I run the project.
`WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/common/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'`

I am totally fed up and broken.
Just 2 months of break from work, I am back at the starting block.

I don't want to post my code and make the question specific.

I want an answer that explains the way in which the server executes a spring project. Right from the running of an application(basic hello world application) to the display of the home page.
This will be helpful for all the beginners.
I tried searching for such an explanation in the net but I didn't get any proper **explanation**, but got a lot of basic samples. Those samples are easy to understand but are not explaining the way in which the server goes about.

**Note:**  I am looking for an answer that explains the Springs concept. From the running of an application to the display of a home page. What all happens in this process? Where does the server start with? How does it go about?

Comment: Providing solution that solves this problem, might be helpful here but a solution to help the beginners understand the whole configuration will be great.

Comment: hwo is your @controller configurations and other component scans

Comment: IN this case you have this URL: `/common/` mapped on your web.xml, but this mapping doesn't exists in any Controller class using `@RequestMapping`

Comment: The HomeController, is it under the com.mkyong.common package?

Comment: @mavroprovato yes it is under the same package.

Comment: I want a wider answer. I am looking not something specific for this question but something that will explain the Spring configuration briefly, so that it is useful for all beginners. Can anyone please explain what happens when we run a project? That is, what will be the step by step procedure in it?

Comment: So let me get this straight: apparently you are not willing to read the excellent reference material ( http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/ ), nor follow the standard tutorials ( http://www.springsource.org/tutorials ), yet you want *everything* explained to you and you think **50** rep is enough for that?

Comment: "
  
 
I want a wider answer." SO is for specific questions. Read the [FAQ]

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd and Raedwald. So, what do you mean to say, I have done a mistake asking for a wider answer? I thought it would be nice to have a brief answer in SO on how the server goes about in Springs. It would be easy for everyone to understand a concept in one go.

Comment: It's just not within this site's scope. If you have a specific question concerning your code, ask (and show your code). If you want a general explanation, this is not the right site. You might want to ask in the Spring Forums instead: http://forum.springsource.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the flow initially servlet container loads the web.xml file.In web.xml we will specify that all the requests are handled by the spring FrontController that is DispatcherServlet.
We include it by adding the following code

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
         <servletclass>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servletclass>
         <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Here it indicate if the url request is of *.htm it is handled by dispatcherServlet then dispatcherServlet load dispatcher-servlet.xml . Where we need to mention the mapping to controller by writing the specific url request such as

```
<bean name="/insert.htm" class="com.controller.MyController"></bean>
```

So in bean we mention that for request of `/insert.htm` it tells the servlet to look in the mentioned class.You need use the Annotation of @RequestMapping above the method for ex

```
@RequestMapping("/insert.htm")
public ModelAndView insert(HttpServletRequest req,Student student)
{
   String name=req.getParameter("name");
    int id=Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("id"));
    student.setId(id);

    return new ModelAndView("display","Student",student);//It returns a view named        display with modelclass name as `Student` and model object student
    }
```

So when a Request url of `/insert.htm` appears it executes the above method it returns a ModelAndView object nothing but an view.It again goes to dispatcher-servlet.xml and looks for view Resolver the normal code that is to be added is

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />
```

So from this it gets the logical view name and appends the prefix and suffix to it .Finally it displays the content in the view.so it looks for display in view resolver prefixes and suffixes the things and finally returns /WEB-INF/jsp/display.jsp  .Which displays the jsp content

Comment: What about the URL? The URL, that appears on the browser for the display of the home page, where is it obtained from? Is it related to the context path or ...?

Comment: yes, still in confusion. The context path is the problem. Whatever I set it to be in the properties 'Web settings', the URL ends up to be localhost:8080/common/

Comment: can you post your web.xml file?

Answer (score 2):

You are mapping your Spring servlet only for requests that end with `.htm`. The request for the root of your application does not end with `.htm` and so, it does not get picked up by Spring. Edit your `web.xml` as follows, in order to use Spring for all requests:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Then, use this as the controller:

```
package com.mkyong.common;

@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("index");
        model.addObject("msg", "hello world");

        return model;
    }
}
```

The controller intercepts the requests for the context root of the application, adds the `msg` attribute to the model and redirects to the `index` view.

So, you need to add the `index.jsp` file in the `/WEB-INF/views/` directory. Inside your jsp, you will be able to use the value of the `msg` attribute.

Comment: What should I write in the `@RequestMapping`?

Comment: I am looking for a more generalized answer. I want to know what happens when the app is run.

Comment: What is the significance of the word "index" in the ModelAndView?

Comment: It is the name of the jsp. You have set this up with the `org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver` in `servlet-context.xml`

Comment: I have added a NOTE to my question. Please see that. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: I changed the context root in Project Settings to "SpringMVC" but still the URL in the browser shows "localhost:8080/commons/". I don't how and what to do.

Answer (score 0):

From what every you have posted you do no have a request mapping for the url `/common/`.

You will have to create another request mapping function like the one below in your controller class and create a view file also.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/common/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView common(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) {

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("common");
    model.addObject("msg", "hello world");

    return model;
}
```

Comment: `common` is a part of the package-name `com.mkyong.common`. I don't know why that appears in the URL at all. My URl when I run the project is `http://localhost:8080/common/`. Again here I don't know why the work `common` is coming into picture.

Comment: what is the context-path of the application?

Comment: Found out the context-root. It is set to `common`. Should I change it to the project-name.

Comment: how is the web.xml also where is it deployed is it tomcat?

Comment: I have updated the question with `web.xml` in it. I am running the project through VMWare vFabric server.

Comment: @Freakyuser another problem is `/` url is not mapped to spring handler, only urls ending with `.htm` are mapping to sping mvc

Comment: @Freakyuser try changing `*.htm` to `/*`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31524/discussion-between-freakyuser-and-arun-p-johny)

Comment: I have added a NOTE to my question. Please see that. Thanks for your help so far.