# No Mapping Found in HTTP Request with URI [springcodes/functions.jsp]

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

Before asking a new question, I have been reading this reference and more possibly duplicate questions:

[No mapping found for HTTP request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17022070/no-mapping-found-for-http-request)

I have already wasted hours hair-pulling just for this to work.

Here is my sample code:

**Dispatcher-servlet**

```
<context:component-scan base-package="springcodes.controller" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**Web.xml**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

**Controller** (This controller appears to be working since my index.jsp successfully displays.)

```
@RequestMapping("/welcome")
public String displayIndex(@RequestParam(value="name", required=false, defaultValue="Guestxx") String name, Model model) {    
    model.addAttribute("name", name);      
    // returns the view name
    return "welcome";
}

@RequestMapping("/")
public String displayIndex2(@RequestParam(value="name", required=false, defaultValue="Guesii") String name, Model model) {    
    model.addAttribute("name", name);
    // returns the view name
    return "welcome";
}
```

**Controller in question**: (when I enter this URL: http://localhost:8080/springcodes/functions.jsp something is supposed to be displayed, **but currently not working**)

```
@Controller
public class FunctionController {

@RequestMapping("/functions")
public String displayFunctionsPage(Model model) {     

    model.addAttribute("funcList", "Function List");
    // returns the view name
    System.out.println("are we inside?");
    return "functions/functionpage";

   }
}
```

Comment: All mappings you showed are in the same Controller class?

Comment: the functions and welcome are of different controllers

Comment: @OpenJDK the welcome page is: http://localhost:8080/springcodes

Comment: @regularslasher what is the name of your app. springcodes?

Comment: When facing problems in hitting URL, a stacktrace with `org.springframework` in info or debug mode **is** useful...

Answer (score 1):

Did you try just 
http://localhost:8080/springcodes/functions ?

And

```
   @RequestMapping("/functions")
   public String displayFunctionsPage(Model model) {     

     model.addAttribute("funcList", "Function List");
     // returns the view name
     System.out.println("are we inside?");
    return "functions/functionpage.jsp";
   }
```

Edit -- 
Since you have not shared complete code , its not easy to guess , still please try below approach -

```
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/functions")
    public class FunctionController {

      @RequestMapping("/page")
      public String displayFunctionsPage(Model model) {     

       model.addAttribute("funcList", "Function List");
       // returns the view name
       System.out.println("are we inside?");
       return "functions/functionpage";
     }
   }
```

URL - 
http://localhost:8080/springcodes/functions/page

Comment: springcodes is a context root of your web application ?

Comment: Yes, [springcodes] is the contextroot of my web app.

Answer (score 1):

There are two different problems here.

First, you **have** an `InternalResourceViewResolver` with a prefix of `/WEB-INF/views/` (and a suffix of `.jsp`) so your return should be :

```
return "functions/functionpage";
```

Do not repeat the prefix nor the suffix.

But another thing smells. Your `DispatcherServlet` is mapped to `/`, not `/*`. Even if both looks like *catchall*, they are indeed different :

- `/*` means : *I want everything* - normally you have to setup a `/<mvc:resource>` tag to allow serving static resources
- `/` means : *I accept everything that nobody else wanted*. That allows all static resources **and JSP** outside `WEB-INF` folder to be served directly by the servlet container.

So the servlet container should try to serve itself the URL `http://localhost:8080/springcodes/functions.jsp` and not even try to pass it to Spring `DispatcherServlet`. But if you fix first problem, `http://localhost:8080/springcodes/functions` should work.

Comment: First problem takes place when returning a view from the controller to load a jsp. I think solving that will not solve the problem of reaching the controller.

Comment: @FranMontero: It won't, but if it is not fixed, it could hide the fact that `/functions` (without `.jsp`) should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to hit this [http://localhost:8080/springcodes/functions].
As you are trying to hit a URI which has no mapping associated because your controller is expecting `springcodes/functions`

Comment: Could you please attach the stacktrace of error with your question?

Comment: And also as suggested by others you should also change the return statement to 'return "functions/functionpage";'

Comment: Aug 05, 2015 7:07:22 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/springcodes/functions]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

Comment: Do you have "/springcodes" requestMapping declaration over your controller?
If not please try [localhost:8080/functions]

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
return "WEB-INF/views/functions/functionpage.jsp";
```

To:

```
return "functions/functionpage";
```

Comment: yes, I also changed that accordingly, still does not work.

Comment: without the ending `.jsp` ? if your file is located in the same directory as your `welcome.jsp` it should work this way if it worked for `welcome.jsp`. can you post your folder-structure?

Comment: to be clear: you are calling this url: [http://localhost:8080/functions](http://localhost:8080/functions) aren't you?

Comment: WEB-INF ---> views (welcome.jsp) --> functions (functionpage.jsp)

Comment: so that means you have a `@RequestMapping("/springcodes")` on your `@Controller`-Class where your `displayFunctionsPage` is located? Else the URL HAS to be [http://localhost:8080/functions](http://localhost:8080/functions) and it should work that way...

Comment: Nope those are all I have in the controllers above. There is no ("/springcodes")

Comment: so @regularslasher  what is the name of your app?

Comment: @FranMontero the name of the app is just "springcodes"

Answer (score 0):

Annotate your controller with `@Controller`

also be sure you have

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.acss.springcodes.controller"/>
```

Pointing at correct package containing your controller.

Comment: When I attempted to add <mvc:annotation-driven/> , even the welcome page gets a 404 error, which is another issue.

Answer (score 0):

The correct mapping for controller is:

```
  @RequestMapping("/functions/**")
```

One has to learn this the hard way.

Answer (score -1):

If your app is deployed correctly and you app name is `springcodes` then you only have to remove `.jsp` from your url as the mapping is just `/functions`: 
`http://localhost:8080/springcodes/functions`
Also check that Controller class has no mapping at class level.

Comment: The usual mapping is: `/appName/ClassLevelMapping/MethodLevelMappping`